# jquery, adding animation to changing background

Tags: jquery, css

is it possible to add animation to changing background. I tried with `CSS3` property `transition` `background and background-image` like this:

```
var affected_element = $('body');
affected_element.css('min-height', '100%');
affected_element.css('min-width', '100%');
affected_element.css('background-size', 'cover');

affected_element.css('transition', 'background 1s');
affected_element.css('-moz-transition', 'background 1s');
affected_element.css('-webkit-transition', 'background 1s');
affected_element.css('-o-transition', 'background 1s');

var config = $('.fullscreen_src');

affected_element.css('background-image', "url('" + config[0].src + "')");
imageIndex = 1,
setInterval(function(){ affected_element.css('background-image', "url('" + config[imageIndex++ % config.length].src + "')" ) }, 3000);
```

but i don't see that transition is taking any effect? Am i doing something wrong or there is easier way to do this?

Comment: nice transition from one image to another, like a transparency

Comment: use fadeIn() and fadeOut()

Comment: using fadein or out is not good because entire page is not visible with it's contents at some time

Comment: Why don't you use a div inside the body tag for the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this plugin: http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

what you would need to do is have normal images and get those behind your content (z-index and content etc is not included in my example):

**html:**

```
<body>
  <div id="background">
    <img src="image1.jpg" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" />
  </div>
</body>
```

**css:**

```
html,body
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body
{
  position: relative;
}
#container, #container img
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
#container img + img
{
  display: none;
}
```

if you want to switch from image1 to image2:

```
$('#background img:eq(1)').fadeIn().siblings().fadeOut();
```

as a jQuery tip in general: you can chain methods:

```
var affected_element = $('body');
affected_element.css('min-height', '100%')
  .css('min-width', '100%')
  .css('background-size', 'cover');
```

or better yet (when using animation or css (and a whole lot of other functions)):

```
var affected_element = $('body');
affected_element.css({
  'min-height': '100%'
  'min-width': '100%',
  'background-size': 'cover'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fadeIn - fadeOut solution:

```
var affected_element = $('body');
affected_element.fadeOut(3000);
affected_element.promise.done(function(){
  $(this).css('background-image',newSource).fadeIn(3000);
});
```

When the fadeOut is finished then the image source is change and showed using the fadeIn animation.

Comment: i don't want to use `fadeout fadein` on `body` tag